# jquery selector to access last cell(Last row's last column) when row is in inline edit mode in JqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

Wanted to add keydown event on tab key press of last cell in jqGrid to add new row.
Please help me out to attach keydown event only to the last cell of a grid when row is in inline mode.
This is the selector to get lastrow

```
var lastRow = $('#grid>tbody>tr.jqgrow:last');
```

1. How to specify last row's last column selector.
2. Please suggest is it possible to dynamically bind event like this.
3. Which place will be better to place this bind event code, like in loadComplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about on `loadcomplete` you get the last row, and then add a class to the last column.  You could then just add a jQuery event handler to this to listen for the tab key to trigger the add new record function.

A rough outline of how you would do so:

Get the Id's of the rows:

```
var rowIds = $(grid).jqGrid('getDataIDs').length;
```

If you know the last column name you can use it or if not you can get the length of the `colNames` array.

```
var lastCol = $(grid).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colNames').length;
```

Then just set a class to the last col in the last row via:

```
$(grid).jqGrid('setCell', rowIds, lastCol, "", 'TabTriggerClass');
```

From there you should have a class on the last column on the last row and you would just bind an event handler, and then the add function, etc.

Comment: Thanks Mark for providing a great solution.

Comment: My answer went above your suggestion,How to get it down ?
I am new to posting questions to stackoverflow

Comment: You can't, if you used my answer mark it as correct (and possibly upvote). The answers are sorted by Active/Sorted/Votes

Comment: I tried to up-vote your answer,but i didn't find anything(question/answer) in vote tab.
How to up-vote ?

Comment: On the left hand side you should have a checkmark on this answer to mark as correct.  The arrows up and down are how you upvote but you need a certain rep level to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i am using your solution

```
var bindEventToLastCell = function(){
    jQuery(".TabTriggerClass").on('keydown', function(e){
        if (e.which == 9 && jQuery(e.currentTarget).hasClass('TabTriggerClass')) {

            $(this).removeClass('TabTriggerClass');
            $(this).off(e);
            //Performing other actions
        }
    });
};

var addTabTriggerClassToLastCell = function(grid) {
    var lastRowId = jQuery('#' + jQuery(grid).attr('id') + '>tbody>tr.jqgrow:last').attr('id');
    var lastCol = getLastEditableColumnIndex(grid);
    grid.setCell(lastRowId, lastCol, "", 'TabTriggerClass');
};
```